# Converting test al,al to c

Tags: c, assembly

How can I code `test al,al` in c language?

I've tried `if((n & 0xFF) & 0){}` but this is not correct.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no 1:1 mapping from assembler to C. It all depends n the context. (Take a look at an assembler manual. The important part of the `test` instruction is setting the flag-register.)

Comment: +1, whatever you're trying to do sounds badly broken.

Comment: `(n & 0xFF) & 0` will always be false.  You need to learn some C before trying to understand assembler.

Comment: Ups, i never learned the C language for trying to understand assembler or CPU specific instructions. Now i notice it at the first time that it can be usefull, but i can not really believe it that it is very helpfull for to understand assembler. I guess it is more helpfull for to understand and for to use the C language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're checking the zero flag next, i.e. `jz` or similar. In that case you'd want

```
if ((n & 0xFFFF) != 0) {
```

Note that

- AX is 16-bit not 8 bit (as e.g. AL and AH are) so you want 0xFFFF not 0xFF (if you even need this restriction)
- `& 0` can only ever give `= 0` and so false.

Comment: sorry i ment test al,al. Thanks for that.